# Populate OneToMany relationship in Criteria

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a entity *AuditLog* which holds a One-to-Many relationship to *AuditParameter*:

```
@Entity
public class AuditLog implements IAuditLog, Serializable {    
    // ...

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = AuditParameter.class, mappedBy = "auditLog")
    private List<IAuditParameter> parameters;
}
```

The *AuditParameter* of cause has a `@ManyToOne(targetEntity = AuditLog.class) private IAuditLog auditLog`.

I would like to fetch all *AuditLog* records with the relationship list already fetched. I tried the following:

```
    Session session = ((EntityManagerImpl)em.getDelegate()).getSession();
    Criteria audits = session.createCriteria(AuditLog.class)
            .setFetchMode("parameters", FetchMode.JOIN);
```

But actually this generates a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Can someone explain to my why this generates an outer join and how to accomplish to just eagerly load the *AuditParameters* into the parameters collection?

Comment: Because that's what the documentation says it does, and because that's the easiest and fastest way to do it. How would you eagerly load the parameters without a left join?

Comment: @JBNizet Okay, that's a point... But the problem is, that the result (`list()`) of the Criteria has one `AuditLog` for each existing `AuditParameter`. I would expect that I receive one element of each `AuditLog` in my output list and the "duplicated" rows are in the relationship list.

Comment: Then add a distinct clause to your HQL query, or call `criteria.setResultTransformer(DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.INSTANCE)` in case of a criteria query.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, this worked. I just read the docs for `Criteria.JOIN`, `Criteria.*`, ...